# How to edit an awk file in emacs 28.2 without using AWK//l mode defined in cc-mode.el

Tags: cc-mode

While trying to edit an awk file with emacs 28.2 its not self-inserting all charcaters, but trying to evaluate certain keystrokes!  For example if I press `3` emacs sees `C-u 3-`!  Pressing `a` causes it to query me for `Cscope Initial Directory`!  Clearly some mode has been enabled that I didn't ask for and don't want!

Looking at modes (`C-h m`) I see:

```
Enabled minor modes: Abbrev Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Blink-Cursor Column-Number Cscope
Display-Fill-Column-Indicator Electric-Indent Engine File-Name-Shadow
Font-Lock Global-Auto-Revert Global-Edit-Server-Edit Global-Eldoc
Global-Font-Lock Global-Undo-Tree Hs Indent-Tabs Line-Number
Mac-Mouse-Wheel Menu-Bar Override-Global Ruler Shell-Dirtrack
Show-Paren Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree Which-Function Winner

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

AWK//l mode defined in ‘cc-mode.el’:
Major mode for editing AWK code.
To submit a problem report, enter ‘M-x c-submit-bug-report’ from an
‘awk-mode’ buffer.  This automatically sets up a mail buffer with version
information already added.  You just need to add a description of the
problem, including a reproducible test case, and send the message.
```

But what enabled `AWK//l` mode?  It's not in **auto-mode-alist**!

For the moment my workaround is to use `find-file-literally`.

`M-x c-submit-bug-report` is also failing - possibly I need to update org-mode - TBC.

Comment: What does Org mode have to do with `c-submit-bug-report`? As for `autto-mode-alist`, it has an entry for `awk` that invoked `awk-mode`: why it shows up as `AWK//l` on the mode line I cannot guess, but I'm pretty sure it's the same mode. BTW, that's a major mode. OTOH, you probably don't need all the minor modes that are enabled. Start with `M-x cscope-mode` which should toggle it off (check with `C-h m` again) and restore `a` to sanity. I'm not sure who would be responsible for the `3` insanity. If worse comes to worst, turn them all off one by one and see which one is the culprit.

Comment: It is not `awk-mode` that does crazy things with the keys:  when I open `foo.awk` it is in `awk-mode` (which shows `AWK//l` on the modeline), but both `3` and `a` are inserted into the buffer. It has to be one of the minor modes that are enabled on that buffer.

Comment: Thanks @NickD for responding.   Interesting, I don't have a `cscope-mode`interactive function.  Using `M-x cscope-minor-mode` says that it turns that off but the digit keys are still assigned, as reported by `C-h k 3` : "3 runs the command digit-argument (found in cscope-list-entry-keymap)".  I recall updating  https://github.com/dkogan/xcscope.el recently, I shall take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in modified [xscope.el function cscope-minor-mode (line 3111:    (use-local-map cscope-list-entry-keymap)))](https://github.com/dkogan/xcscope.el/pull/31/files#diff-b03ff88fd10ce5cf23065ac9f6172ab9ae8e8fe0739866082d2b679194757c69) , which is enabled via a hook in my init.el

```
(require 'xcscope)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'cscope-minor-mode)
```

That bug is not present in the [official upstream version](https://%20https://github.com/dkogan/xcscope.el), I have updated to that.